# I tried to add userinfo to localstorrage but it didnt work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

Hello guys i want help running this code because i try my best and i didnt find a solution.
i want to add the user info entered from the form to the localstorage so i can use them later for the active session until logging out.
here the code below

**here is the register js file :**

```
async function registerUser(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:2090/api/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        role,
        name,
        email,
        password,
      }),
    })

    const data = await response.json()

    if (data.status === 'ok') {
      localStorage.setItem('user', data.user)
      navigate('/login')
    } else {
      alert('User already exists !!')
    }
  }
```

**and here is the register api from server indexjs file:**

```
app.post('/api/register', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    try {
        const user = await User.create({
            role: req.body.role,
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password,
        })
        res.json( { status: 'ok' , user: user })
    }catch (err) {
        res.json({ status: 'error', error: 'Duplicate email' })
    }
})
```

Comment: please provide some more info, the client getting the response just an error while saving to localStorage? or maybe the problem in the server while creating the user? one or both catch blocks run?

Comment: you need to use `JSON.stringify(localStorage.setItem('user', data.user))`

Comment: What is the behavior you see, and why is it unexpected/not what you want? Have you tried to check what is saved in localStorage in the browser, and what is sent back and forth with your register HTTP request? It would be helpful to hear what debugging steps you have taken, and what you found.

Answer (score 0):

Hey it's slightly unclear where the issue is but incase your issue is with getting the user data from `localStorage`, I'll write this here:

`localStorage` is only able to store `String`, so [all non-string types need to be cast to string before they are saved in localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). When an `object` is implicitly cast to `string`, it returns `[object Object]`.

If you want to store an `object` in there, your best bet is to deserialise it with [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and the serialise it again whenever you want to access it with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

*Example*

```
const user = { id: 'test-id' };

localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));

const userFromStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

console.log(userFromStorage); // { id: 'test-id' }
```

You might want to wrap `JSON.parse()` in a try/catch block incase the user isn't set or the stored object is malformed since it will throw an error.

Comment: thansk you guys its working now <3

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert to the string  and only store to the `localstorage` as json data is not supported by `localstorage` and `sessionstorage` using

`localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data.user))`

and retrieve the data and parse using

`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))`

Comment: thansk you guys its working now <3